# Invalid Next Control variable Reference

Tags: excel, vba, loops, iteration

After editing my code, i am getting an invalid next control variable reference. Is anyone able to provide an explanation of what is causing this issue? the reason for the order of my loop is because i'd like to first check all columns of a row then all move onto the new row before looking for a new match

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Loops through data and finds matches and then indexs information
'
Dim J As Integer
Dim P As Integer
Dim v As Integer
IRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Row

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set Master = Sheets("Master")

For J = 1 To IRowL
    For v = 21 To IRowL
        For P = 1 To IRowL

           If cell.value(j,11)= Master.cell.value(p,1) and Cell.value(j,10) = Master.cell.value(p,v) then



              cell.Value(j, 30) = Master.cell.Value(p, 7)
              cell.Value(j, 31) = Master.cell.Value(p, 8)

           Else
           End If
        Next p
    Next v
Next J

'
End Sub
```

[image: Starting point]

[image: the information i want to grab]

I want to grab information from column B (second picture) and the column name in which the dates match Column K from the first picture.

Comment: Looks like your first problem is an extra "End if"

Comment: another problem is the `Then` is on a stand alone line, which will not compile. A screenshot sample of what you are trying to do will come in handy as well. Very hard to know what you are trying to accomplish with just the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ScottHoltzman i've added some photos to help explain what i'm trying to accomplish. the more information that is provided via feedback the better i'll learn how to complete this code and future codes.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the pics, but they did not show up :(did not

Comment: i'm seeing them in my browser and when i log off. Is something that i may be doing that would result in only me seeing the images? I followed the tutorial with ![named image] (imger.link.png)

Answer (score 1):

Next v and Next P are on the wrong lines, that's what the error is telling you. When you run Next P, you are already out of the P loop.

Try reversing the lines and it should run.

If there is some specific problem you are trying to solve by explicitly mixing the 'Next' statements, can you explain a bit more? There are clearer ways to do things like that.

Comment: i fixed my code to your recommendation and now i am getting run time error 424. two of these cell.values will be text so should i change the dim's of those variables to strings?

Comment: I don't see where you are assigning any cell values to variables. But your best bet is probably to use Variant. Slightly less optimal but will probably save you a few headaches.

Comment: I tried used Variant but i'm still getting runtime error 424 on this part of the code. `If cell.Value(J, 11) = Master.cell.Value(P, 1) And cell.Value(J, 10) = Master.cell.Value(P, V)`

Comment: Try Cell(x, y).value instead of Cell.value(x, y)